# How to resolve crossdomain issues in Opeara when i consuming the webservice in Asp.net App?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'myserviceurl/GetName.ashx',
                data: { name:"naresh"},
                dataType: "text/plain",
                xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: true
                     },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    alert("before send");
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("Success :  " +msg);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                alert("Error" +err);
                }
            });
```

I am using above Source code for Consuming the WebService in my Asp.Net Application.
My Service handler returns a string Message.
Above code working in IE9 with Success Message.
but When i run the application in Chrome /Opera i am getting the Success Message as null and some times showing undefined success.
In fiddler showing the Success Message but not in Browser(Chrome/Opera).
****Now i am getting below error : " XMLHttpRequest cannot load MYSERVICEURL.
Origin MYASP.NETAPPLICATIONURL is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Now my question is :
Where i need to change in my code to run in the Chrome/opera ?

Note:

1)when i host ServiceHandler and Asp.Net WebApplication hosted into my IIS it's working                        in all Browsers.

2)Now i didn't hosted my Asp.Net WebApplication into iis , just  i  run into browser(Chrome and Operar) then i am getting above error.

Anybody suggestions would be appreciates.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSONP instead of jSON.

Also you should try

crossdomain: true

Comment: yeah i tried what u suggested.now success message also not showing. showing same error as :"XMLHttpRequest cannot load MYSERVICEURL. Origin MYASP.NETAPPLICATIONURL is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."